# Reuse Value from SELECT in WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to reuse a value from `SELECT` in a `WHERE` clause?
Actually I would be fine if it would be possible the other way around: reuse a value from `WHERE` in `SELECT`. I just want to increase readability and eventually performance: I guess a modern SQL Server won't calculate the value twice.

```
SELECT `e`.*, (datediff(e.start, 'someValue')) AS `offset`
FROM `event` AS `e`
WHERE `offset` % someInterval = 0
```

instead

```
SELECT `e`.*, (datediff(e.start, 'someValue')) AS `offset`
FROM `event` AS `e`
WHERE (datediff(e.start, 'someValue')) % someInterval = 0
```

Comment: You can refer to `SELECT` aliases in `HAVING`, but not `WHERE`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`:

```
SELECT `e`.*, (datediff(e.start, 'someValue')) AS `offset`
FROM `event` AS `e`
HAVING `offset` % someInterval = 0
```

`WHERE` is used to decide which rows to put into the result set, so you would have an infinite regress if you could refer to the results at the same time as selecting them.

`HAVING` is used to filter the results after they're calculated.

Comment: he said he wanted to improve readability by not having to repeat the expression.

Comment: I think in some cases `HAVING` does improve performance. MySQL can sometimes tell that the value of the result column doesn't depend on aggregation, so it performs the test while it's generating the results, rather than having to make a second pass.

Comment: It would be illustrative to compare the performance of my answer with Phil Walton's.

Comment: +1.  For large sets, I'd go with repeating the expression in the `WHERE` clause; OP wants to avoid that, and unfortunately, the predicate isn't sargable (at least, not without creating an index on a column that stores the result of the expression.) So my next choice, woud be to go with the `HAVING` clause. That's preferable to implementing an inline view that's going to require MySQL to materialize the entire set as a derived table, and the requery the derived table. (With trivially small sets, we aren't going to notice a performance difference.)

Answer (score 1):

Here ya go...

```
SELECT t.* FROM (
  SELECT `e`.*, (datediff(e.start, NOW())) AS `offset`
  FROM `event` AS `e`
) t
WHERE t.`offset` % 2 = 0;
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f84f1/3)